# Http original request up address

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-httpclient

I am trying to retrieve the up address from an angular application calling a web API through a load balancer. I want the actual ip address of the device making the call and not the address of the load balancer. Is there a way to keep that information in the request? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify? In probably 99% of cases, clients are located behind NAT and their local IP is irrelevant. The public IP should be available at the server.

Comment: Everything happens inside the local network. There is no internet connection involved.

Comment: Then why the proxy? That's what a proxy does- it obfuscates IPs.

Comment: It was a load balancer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you configure the LB to add header information for the original requester?